# How to select values with XSLT from unstructed XML with numbered occurences

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

For a label printing function I'm trying to understand how I can use XSLT and value-of select to retrieve values from an unstructed xml-output.

See the example below where the tags I3 and I4 is related if the "occ" (occurence) number is equal between the two tags.

The I4 tag describes the type of value, and the I3 is the actual value.
For instance: "I3" occ="1">123 is related to "I4" occ="1" other number.

example:

```
<field tag="I3" occ="1">123</field>
<field tag="I4" occ="1" lang="sv-SE" invariant="true">other number</field>
<field tag="I3" occ="2">324</field>
<field tag="I4" occ="2" lang="sv-SE" invariant="true">find number</field>
<field tag="I3" occ="3">1203</field>
<field tag="I4" occ="3" lang="sv-SE" invariant="true">FID</field>
<field tag="I3" occ="4">321-35-2000</field>
<field tag="I4" occ="4" lang="sv-SE" invariant="true">archive number</field>
```

Is there a way with XSLT 1.0 to do this kind of select operation? My knowledge is limited to how I could select for instance the tag I3 with occ=3, as such:

```
<xsl:value-of select="field[@tag='I3' and @occ='4']" /></xsl:text>
```

but the data I'm selecting values from will not be similiar each time (the occurance och the type-tag will not always have the same order, and sometimes on or several of the types will not exist).

Any suggestions? Thanks for any input!

The output I want is something like:

```
<data>other number: 123</data>
<data>find number: 324</data>
<data>FID: 1203</data>
<data>archive number: 321-35-2000</data>
```

Updated output - I realised that I need each I4 tag as element name, otherwise the printer service cannot use the lines as source for printing output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<output>  
  <variable name="other number">123</variable>  
  <variable name="find number">324</variable>  
  <variable name="FID">1203</variable>  
  <variable name="archive number">321-35-2000</variable>  
</output>
```

Comment: Could you give an example of *"sometimes on or several of the types will not exist"* and what should be the result in such case?

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure that one of the elements of the pair will always be there, you could use that element for your initial selection. Then use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)** to retrieve the other member of the pair (which may or may not exist).

In this example we assume that `<field tag="I3">` always exists:

**XML**

```
<fields>
    <field tag="I3" occ="1">123</field>
    <field tag="I4" occ="1" lang="sv-SE" invariant="true">other number</field>
    <field tag="I3" occ="2">324</field>
    <field tag="I4" occ="2" lang="sv-SE" invariant="true">find number</field>
    <field tag="I3" occ="3">1203</field>
    <field tag="I4" occ="3" lang="sv-SE" invariant="true">FID</field>
    <field tag="I3" occ="4">321-35-2000</field>
    <field tag="I4" occ="4" lang="sv-SE" invariant="true">archive number</field>
</fields>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="type" match="field[@tag='I4']" use="@occ" />

<xsl:template match="/fields">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="field[@tag='I3']">
            <data>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('type', @occ)"/>
                <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </data>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <data>other number: 123</data>
  <data>find number: 324</data>
  <data>FID: 1203</data>
  <data>archive number: 321-35-2000</data>
</output>
```

---

### Added:

If you change:

```
            <data>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('type', @occ)"/>
                <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </data>
```

to:

```
            <variable name="{key('type', @occ)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </variable>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <variable name="other number">123</variable>
  <variable name="find number">324</variable>
  <variable name="FID">1203</variable>
  <variable name="archive number">321-35-2000</variable>
</output>
```

Read about [attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates).

Comment: Thank you for your very quick reply! It works great! Do you know how I could get each I4-tag as an element label, for example:  <other number>123</other number> and the following tags. I realised I need each line to be unique to be able to select them with the label printing service.

Comment: @FredrikAndersson Technically, you could use the `xsl:element` instruction to create an element with a given name. However, `"other number"` is not a valid element name. Consider if a format like `<data name="other number">123</data>` can work for you.

Comment: Thank you! I tried some variations but haven't been able to solve how to get the I4-tag as part of the element name. I need the matched I4 to be part of the element name but I don't understand how to fix it. This output would solve my problem:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<output>  
  <variable name="other number">123</variable>  
  <variable name="find number">324</variable>  
  <variable name="FID">1203</variable>  
  <variable name="archive number">321-35-2000</variable>  
</output>`

Comment: @FredrikAndersson Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and add this as the output you now want.

Comment: @FredrikAndersson See the addition to my answer.